# How to fix this error with efs.csi.controller in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, controller, helm

I'm trying to setup some efs volumes under kubernetes but I get some errors when trying to do so, when going back to check my efs csi controller logs, specifically the efs-provisioner container, I find this error repeating infinitly:

```
error retrieving resource lock kube-system/efs-csi-aws-com: leases.coordination.k8s.io "efs-csi-aws-com" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:efs-csi-controller-sa" cannot get resource "leases" in API group "coordination.k8s.io" in the namespace "kube-system"
```

Any idea about this error message or how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

The service account efs-csi-controller-sa in the kube-system namespace doesn't have the necessary permissions to perform the requested operation, specifically retrieving a resource (leases) in the coordination.k8s.io API group within the kube-system namespace.

You need to grant the appropriate RBAC (Role-Based Access Control) permissions to the service account. You can do this by creating or modifying the RBAC roles and role bindings.

You might need to create a ClusterRole and bind it to the service account in the kube-system namespace, see this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).